# Create AWS Lambda Function using Boto3 Python Code?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I need to create a lambda function using from scratch option. I see there are 3 options in AWS Application. I went through AWS Boto3 document but unable to find the way to select 3 ways of selecting.

I tried looking into Boto3 Doc. My code is failing for S3 key. How can I create a simple lambda function using Boto3 code!

My code:

```
  lambda_Client = boto3.client('lambda', aws_access_key_id=accessKey,
                       aws_secret_access_key=secretKey,region_name=region)
  response =lambda_Client.create_function(
            Code={
                'S3Bucket': 's3bucket',
                'S3Key': 'function.zip', #how can i create or fetch this S3Key
            },
            Description='Process image objects from Amazon S3.',
            FunctionName='function_name',
            Handler='index.handler',
            Publish=True,
            Role='arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/lambda-role',
            Runtime='nodejs12.x',
        )

        print(response)
```

Error:
GetObjet S3 key is invalid.

How can I create an s3 key or is there a simple way to create an AWS Lambda Function without any dependency. Please guide me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This key would come from uploading an object to Amazon S3, you can do this programmatically by calling [put_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) via the Boto3 SDK.

A rough example of how to use would be the following

```
import zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('function.zip', 'w')
zip.write('index.js', 'path/on/disk/index.js')
.......

client.put_object(Body=archive, Bucket='bucket-name', Key='function.zip')

lambda_Client = boto3.client('lambda', aws_access_key_id=accessKey,
                       aws_secret_access_key=secretKey,region_name=region)
response = lambda_Client.create_function(
            Code={
                'S3Bucket': 'bucket-name',
                'S3Key': 'function.zip', #how can i create or fetch this S3Key
            },
            Description='Process image objects from Amazon S3.',
            FunctionName='function_name',
            Handler='index.handler',
            Publish=True,
            Role='arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/lambda-role',
            Runtime='nodejs12.x',
        )
```

You specify the key when you upload this, make sure that you zip your code when you upload it.

Alternatively use the `ZipFile` attribute instead, from the [Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_function) it states the following.

> The base64-encoded contents of the deployment package. AWS SDK and AWS CLI clients handle the encoding for you.

Comment: I have added a rough example of this which should indicate how it should be implemented

Comment: Your Lambda role that you're specifying just need to have the permission for `xray:PutTraceSegments` added to its policy. Alternatively add the `AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess` managed policy to your role :)

Comment: Ok Thanks, I am usning python 3.7.3 For the code
import zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('function.zip', 'w')
zip.write('index.js', 'path/on/disk/index.js')
I am getting error as AttributeError: type object 'zip' has no attribute 'write'

write is not getting highlighted whereas import zip is going to proper library when clicked on it

Comment: I just need to upload a zip file and not write how can i do that?

Comment: Oops, that should have been `archive.write`

Answer (score 7):

I found a lot of problems trying to create a lambda function with the a zip file, but finally I did this and worked.

This code will create a lambda function from a ZIP file:

First we declare the path of the zip file
Then on the `aws_file` function we convert it into bytes so amazon can read it
Finally the `lambda_creator` will upload it and create the lambda function with the parameters given

```
ZIPNAME = "code\\my-deployment-package.zip"


def aws_file():
    with open(ZIPNAME, 'rb') as file_data:
        bytes_content = file_data.read()
    return bytes_content


def lambda_creator(name):
    lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', aws_access_key_id=ACCESSKEY,
                                 aws_secret_access_key=SECRETKEY, region_name=REGION)
    response = lambda_client.create_function(
        Code={
            'ZipFile': aws_file()
        },
        Description='Hello World Test.',
        FunctionName='Test-lambda',
        Handler='lambda_function.lambda_handler',
        Publish=True,
        Role='arn:aws:iam:: 123456789012:role/lambda-rol',
        Runtime='python3.8',
    )
    return response
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.